# draft.js Text inline styles while copying between two editors

Tags: draftjs

Is it possible copy/paste text between two editors with saving inline styles?

Here is an example: (https://jsfiddle.net/m6z0xn4r/1295/)

If you format text in the first editor (with using H1, H2 ...) buttons, copy formatted text and paste copied text into another one editor you will get text without inline styles (H1, H2 ...) in editor.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/m6z0xn4r/1295/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems to be possible, if you try copying from your fiddle and pasting into the editor on the https://draftjs.org/ homepage you will see that the styles are preserved there. In fact, even in your example it seems to work for me, albeit with a few bugs (heading didn't get copy/pasted but bold text and blockquote did). Based on the Draft.js documentation (see: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/81cc54b908a7463409ce80c785585a65b3646340/docs/APIReference-Editor.md#strippastedstyles) it looks like this is default behaviour and you actually have to disable it for styles to be stripped. Perhaps you are encountering a bug/edge case where it doesn't work for whatever reason? It does look like there's an open issue w/r/t this and a pull request with a possible fix: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/787 and https://github.com/thibaudcolas/draftjs-conductor#idempotent-copy-paste-between-draftjs-editors

Comment: The main point is that header tags (H1, H2 ...) don't work by pasting